# How to root a LG-E405?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, lg

I wanted to do this because it's a small phone so moving to the sdcard is a good option to me so... anyone can help me?

I am a linux (OpenSuse) user so if there a solution using the terminal or something it's great!

```
about the phone:
phone - LG-E404.
Android - 2.3.6
Kernel - 2.6.38.6-perf+
compilation - GRK39F
Software Version - V10f-SEP-14-1012
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok saddly I have to use a Windows machione to acomplish that. But that was pretty easy after all.

1. Search for the drivers of your smartphone.I find mine in here:
   http://www.mylgphones.com/lg-android-usb-device-drivers
2. Install a rooter software, searching I found this
   http://www.kingoapp.com/android-root.htm
3. Set you phone in debug mode.
4. Finally install the drivers, the use the software and there you go
   My phone is rooted...